# Batch file to find file with name ending with unique number

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder with files that are named this way:

```
abc_123_1234567.txt
```

How can I write a Windows7 batch-file that finds the file in the folder which matches the last set of numbers (i.e. 1234567).

So, a call to the batch-file: `mybatchfile.bat 1234567` returns the above file. Note the number is unique and so returns only one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mybatchfile.bat contents:

`dir /b *%1*`

or

`dir /b *_%1.txt`

Comment: How can I put the result into a variable so I can use it later in the batch file program

Comment: `dir /b *_%1.txt >tmp1`

Comment: `set /p myvar= <tmp1`

Comment: Sorry, but still don't know HOW to add new line in comments! The site has to think about this (and get normal HELP).

Answer (score 0):

Main routine

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
CALL c:\106x\q27293854a.bat 1234563
popd
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL% filefound=%filefound%
GOTO :EOF
```

Where `1234563` is your target name
Note: You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. That particular setting suits my system.
`c:\106x\q27293854a.bat` is the called batchname - name is unimportant (that suits my system) but can simply be `q27293854a` if the file is installed on a directory in the `path`.

Called batch `c:\106x\q27293854a.bat`

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SET "filefound="
FOR %%a IN (*_%1.*) DO IF DEFINED filefound (SET "filefound=Error - multiple files found"&EXIT /b 8) else (set "filefound=%%~fa")
IF NOT DEFINED filefound EXIT /b 4
EXIT /b 0
```

This routine will set `filefound` to either the full filename found or nothing if it's not found or an error string if more than one match is found.

`ERRORLEVEL` is also set to 0 for fine - found 1, 4 for `missing` and 8 for `multiple match found`.